# Issue with mysql query, find single rows while it's returning multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project with specific requirement. I am facing issue with sql query. I need to find single single rows for a product which have specific categories(more than one) assigned to it. It should return only one product id for a product. Please see following image.

Table image

[image]

According to this table, product id 1 and 2 are assigned to categories 3,4 and 6. We need to create sql which can find one or more products which have specific categories assigned to it(like 1 and have 3,4,6 categories association). Category parent relation is coming from another table. It has 4 level hierarchy. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, its many to many relation table. So the query should look like this:

`select *
from product p
inner join product_category pc on p.id = pc.product_id
inner join category c on pc.category_id = c.id
where c.id = 3 AND c.id = 4 AND c.id = 6`